# ng-pattern for alphanumeric and all special symbol characters

Tags: angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

In input, I need to allow alphanumeric and all special symbol character.
I am using the following pattern. Unfortunatelly, it is not working.

```
ng-pattern="/^[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#$=!%^)(]:*;?/\,}{'|<>[&+-]*$/"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed to escape all the characters that should be excaped with `\`. The following may work:

```
ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9_@.#$=!%^)(\]:\*;\?\/\,}{'\|<>\[&\+-]*$/"
```

Note that it could be simplified to:

```
ng-pattern="/^[A-z\d_@.#$=!%^)(\]:\*;\?\/\,}{'\|<>\[&\+-]*$/"
```

#### [Test it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7Hj1qb/3)

Comment: this allowing space

Comment: @Nithin Updated, not anymore. :-)